# How to set continous MediaPlayer playback without interrupton after tilt?

Tags: java, android

Please I want to know how to set my `MediaPlayer` to playback continuously without stopping when activity screen rotates? The challenge I'm having now is that when playing is in progress and I happen to tilt the screen the music stops and will require another action to have it play again.

**this is the part of which plays the music in my Activity**

```
// setting up media players

public void  play(View v) {
    if (player == null) {
        //then here, I sent the position of the chosen song in the intent extras.
        //the get back the extra
        int position = 0;
        try{
            position=getIntent().getIntExtra("soundfile",0);
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String fileToPlay="song_"+position;
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, position);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Hymn Tune Playing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        soundSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        soundSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                if (fromUser){
                    player.seekTo(progress);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                soundSeekBar.setProgress(player.getCurrentPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                player.getCurrentPosition();
            }
        });
        player.setLooping(true);
        player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

            }
        });
    }
    player.start();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Playing Continues...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    soundThread = new Thread(this);
    soundThread.start();
}

public void pause(View v) {
    if (player != null) {
        player.pause();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Hymn Tune Paused", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    }
}

public void stop(View v) {
    stopPlayer();
}

private void stopPlayer() {
    if (player != null) {
        player.release();
        player = null;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Hymn Tune Stoped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    stopPlayer();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    int currentPosition = 0;
    int soundTotal = player.getDuration();
    soundSeekBar.setMax(soundTotal);
    while (player != null && currentPosition < soundTotal){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(300);
            currentPosition = player.getCurrentPosition();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException soundException){
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception otherException){
            return;
        }
        soundSeekBar.setProgress(currentPosition);
    }

}

@Override
public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must move your playback code to background service, as those will run constantly while activity is stopped and restarted during tilting. Check out extensive guide to services here

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services